# Build an array from existing arrays?

Tags: java, arrays

```
int[] StarTime = new int[20]; 
int[] duration = new int[40]; 
int[] EndTime = new int[StarTime.length];            
StarTime[0] = 0;                

ExponentialDistribution exp = new ExponentialDistribution(4.0);
    for(int j = 1; j < 20; j++){
        StarTime[j] = (int)exp.sample() + 1+StarTime[j-1];

    }
    for(int k = 0; k < 20;k ++){
        duration[k] = 20 + (int)(Math.random() * ((120 - 10) + 1));
    }
```

I have two arrays StarTime and duration. I want to build an array whose each index is assigned the value which is sum of the values of the indexes of these two arrays. Like suppose EndTime is the array I want to create and  if StarTime[0] is 2 and duration[0] is 4 and EndTime[0] should be 6.

How should I do this?

Comment: This is how i declared array type"

int[] StarTime = new int[20];
int[] duration = new int[40];
int[] EndTime = new int[StarTime.length];

Comment: what does `exp.sample()` returns?

Comment: Something is missing in that question. If you simply do int[] StarTime = new int[20]; int[] duration = new int[40]; int[] EndTime = new int[StarTime.length]; EndTime[0] = StarTime[0]+duration[0]; there are no type errors.

Comment: Show us the error you claimed.  e.g. Make a little compilable example to show that line is giving type mismatch error.  And, when you write any language, make sure you follow consistent naming convention.  For example in Java, variable name should be `endTime` instead of `EndTime`

Comment: I dont see any errors in here. I guess  you are missing something. can  you show us the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason for giving type mismatch, while you are adding two `int` array into another `int` array. It should work:

```
for(int k = 0; k < 20; k++){
    EndTime[k] = StarTime[k] + duration[k];
}
```

Ensure that `exp.sample()` is really casting into `int`. Also ensure the arrays are of same type.

Comment: Yes exp.sample() is casting into int.

It worked. Thanks